# Run-time error '7': out of memory vb6 application

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

i have an vb6 application who works fine with all machine except windows 7 on the specific conditions.
it works fine on XP,Seven,8 and etc but on the systems who has Crystal Report 8.5 installed get

```
Run-time error '7': out of memory
```

please any one help me on this:
if i install CR first then install my app it works fine but when i setup my app then setup CR i get this error !
please anyone help me in this.
THanl U all!

Comment: reinstall my app doesn't work and my app does not any dependency with FM20.dll

Comment: Could you indicate some code where this error happens?  You'll want to test this by installing VB6 on the Windows 7 machine and running your program from there.  I really doubt it's a Windows 7-specific issue.

Comment: Add logging, find out which line triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this 'out of memory' error caused by a broken or missing dependency.

The dependency may not be a direct dependency, but could be further down the line - a dependency of one of your dependencies.

Look at any common files between your app and Crystal Reports, looks like they are using different versions of the same file.